# How to disable all functions on a tablet and allow only one page to be displayed?

Tags: html, google-chrome, tablet, google-developers-console

I have developed several pages that function as a customer service evaluation system. Now, I need a way to prevent the client from exiting the evaluator pages, in a manner where they cannot access settings, go back, go to the home screen, or perform any other actions on the tablet.

Is there a way to achieve this using an application?

Comment: Sounds like you want kiosk mode.